# MySQL JOIN two tables by one value and take other results (without that value too)

Tags: mysql, join

I have some problem with a mySQL query.

The **table** **A** is this:

- A.id
- A.value1
- A.user

**Table** **B** is:

- B.id
- B.user

I need to find value_that_i_need from query, by searching for **B.user**.
But I don't need only values with A.user, i need **all** values from Table A with the same A.id (inside Table A) that matches B.user.

So I need all distinct id (where there is **B.user=A.user**) and search for them inside table A by A.id.

I want to avoid 2 different queries! Already tried differents JOIN, nothing works for me.

EDIT

Ok, i will ty to explain the problem in a easiest way.

```
I have this table: 
+---------+------------+
| id_user | another_id |
+---------+------------+

id_user -> unique id for each user
another_id -> an id related to something like a group
```

another_id can be the same to more users, but i need to take only users who are inside my same groups.
So i will have to check my groups (by searching my id_user) and then i have to see all users with my same another_id.

Problem is that if i query something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table0 AS t0, something_like_groups AS slg    
JOIN user_inside_group as uig ON slg.id_group=uig.group_id AND slg.id_user='my_user_id'
WHERE slg.id='id_group' AND t0.user_id=uig.user_id
```

Actually i have to join 3 tables, but the problem is that i need to find the "group" inside i am and get ALL informations about all users inside my same group. (without an additional query)

Comment: please provide some sample data and expected output in table format

Comment: Your request doesn't make sense: You said *i need all values from Table A with the same A.id (inside Table A) that matches B.user* and i thought **so a.id = b.user?**. then you said *where there is B.user=A.user* and I then thought **so a.user=b.user? Which column is it that is equal to b.user - a.id or a.user?**. Please revise your question and remove these ambiguities/read it out to a co-worker.. fa06's suggestion is probably most helpful if youre struggling to concisely describe things - just show us the data and we'll draw conclusions about how it relates/needs to be queried

Comment: Please do not append EDITs/UPDATEs. Edit your post to be the best presentation possible. Adding more to something unclear does not make it clear. Please also read & act on [mcve]. PS Your addition is not clear either. Please use enough words & phrases & sentences & references to parts of examples. Don't try to cram everything into one sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you just want to find the min id based on b user and then get all the rows from a which match. for example

```
drop table if exists t,t1;
create table t( id int,user varchar(10));
create table t1( id int,user varchar(10));


insert into t values
(1,'aaa'),(1,'bbb'),(2,'ccc');
insert into t1 values
(1,'bbb'),(2,'ccc')
;

select t.id,t.user 
from t
join
(
select t1.user,min(t.id) minid
from t1
join t on t.user = t1.user
group by t1.user
) s
on t.id = s.minid;

+------+------+
| id   | user |
+------+------+
|    1 | aaa  |
|    1 | bbb  |
|    2 | ccc  |
+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```